# Access Enum properties in angular js select drop down

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, enums

I have an enum in java like so

```
public enum myEnum{
   enum1("enumDisplayVal1"), enum2("enumDisplayVal2")
   myEnum(String displayValue) { this.displayValue = displayValue;}

   private String displayValue;
   public String getDisplayValue(){return displayValue}
}
```

In Angular js I create a select dropdown with the enum .

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" id="enumDropDown"
    data-ng-change="update()"
    data-ng-options="e for e in myEnumValues"
    data-ng-model="selectedEnum">
    <option value="">All</option>
  </select>
```

The dropdown shows values like enum1 ,enum2 which are the actual values of the enum. How can I make it so that it shows the "displayValue" property of the enum in the select dropdown.

I send the values of enum to angular js using  `myEnum.values()`

Comment: Have you tried overriding `toString` in your `enum`?

Comment: Hmm. I will try that out. Thanks

Comment: Nope seems to have the same effect @Mena

Comment: if you print whole list like {{myEnumValues}}, what you see ?

Comment: I see an array of names like ['enum1','enum2'] . That is why i was confused if it is an angular js thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing . Created a map of the enum values() like so,

```
 Arrays.stream(myEnum.values()).collect(toMap(i -> i.name(), i -> i.getDisplayValue())
```

On the Angular js side :

```
 <select class="multiselect"  data-ng-change="update()"
                data-ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myEnumValues"
                data-ng-model="selectedEnum">
                <option value="">All</option>
   </select>
```

Solved the issue of having a separate display name and different values.

Comment: Don't know if there is any way to do it without converting to a map. But this solved the issue i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

.....

 @JsonValue
 public String getDisplayValue(){return displayValue}
```